# Can a bootable external drive be used on a different Mac?

Tags: macos, backup, startup

According to [this post on the Carbon Copy Cloner web site](https://bombich.com/blog/2021/05/19/beyond-bootable-backups-adapting-recovery-strategies-evolving-platform), it is no longer possible to boot your Mac to an external bootable clone if the internal storage is not working.  This at least partially defeats the purpose of making a bootable clone.

I want to know if it almost fully defeats the purpose.  Can I still boot a different Mac (which still has working internal storage) to my bootable clone?

In other words, let's say we have 2 Macs, named Asterix and Obelix.  If I clone Asterix's drive, and then Asterix's internal storage fails, can I plug the clone of Asterix into Obelix and boot it up there?

[This other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277279/can-i-boot-from-a-bootable-clone-on-different-mac-models) has an answer that would seem to suggest "yes", but it is many years older than the blog post mentioning Apple having gutted this ability, and therefore doesn't give any indication whether that ability was preserved into the present or not.

Comment: That inability refers specifically to ARM Mac, if it matters.

Comment: iconoclast: Why would the failure of Asterix have any bearing on the ability of Obelix to boot from the clone?

Comment: Are your Macs Intel or Apple silicon? Generally I think the answer is yes so long as the platform is the same. Test your recovery procedure!!  But see my answer to your other question about bootable clones.

Comment: @Gilby: the one I'm concerned about uses ARM.  Thanks for your help on both issues!

Comment: @DavidAnderson: It is not the failure of Asterix that matters, but the fact that I'm trying to boot a clone of Asterix on Obelix rather than on Asterix.

Comment: The answer (yes) is here https://eclecticlight.co/2022/11/26/booting-two-apple-silicon-macs-from-one-external-disk/ and the many related pages on Howard Oakley's blog. It is more complicated with Arm than Intel because a) the boot process always involves the internal disk and b) more security with volume ownership.